# how i can get file created date

Tags: c, windows

i want to know when a file is created.I want to know it's date when it is created
Windows 7 OS

Comment: What operating system do you have in mind? The exact procedure for obtaining a file's creation date is going to be different between operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming windows OS, you can use [GetFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`GetFileInformationByHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).